# FACEBOOK GRAPH API Error :The redirect_uri URL must be absolute

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I try to practice [this code](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498/)
**Scenario 1: Uploading a photo to the app’s album**

And there is error: The redirect_uri URL must be absolute

I just edit these sentences.

```
$app_id = "2***********02";
$app_secret = "******************edf965";
$post_login_url = "localhost/curl_prac/14.0_edition/testfb2.php";
```

Is it because I can't use localhost??

Please tell me what's wrong.Thank you.

Comment: Probably.  Have you tried using a real URL?

Comment: No.I think I have to apply one.Now I know I cam't use localhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you cannot upload a photo from localhost you have to put a 'placeholder' real image url for your tests
Moreover you are giving a relative path not an absolute one so you must be using the 'picture' parameter, either supply an absolute path or use the 'url' parameter instead.

I've never tried something like 'C://path/to/image' tho it could work.

Comment: Thanks a lot.I can move on now.